# Send array in form data POST to PHP endpoint

Tags: javascript, php, parameters

I'm sending values in http request to my PHP endpoint. I used to do like this:

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('postName', 'value');
```

but now I need to send array I tried multiple ways like this

```
params.append('postName', ["value1", "value2"]);
```

this convert to string value1,value2

```
params.append('postName', 'value1');
params.append('postName', 'value2');
```

this just send two strings. How I can pass an array?

I'm using this URLSearchParams because otherwise when I just send object or array then `$_POST['postName']` is not available in php endpoint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have a PHP array after POST request, you need to create an HTML input element with the name that contains square brackets.
In your case:

```
params.append('postName[]', 'value1');
params.append('postName[]', 'value2');
```

In PHP you will have `$_POST['postName']` that will be an array.